# Selenium FireFox Driver stops responding after pop-up disappears

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I would appreciate some thoughts on a problem at hand that I've been trying to solve for 1-2 days.

I am running a Python script with Selenium 2.53.6 on FireFox 49.0.1. The script is supposed to click a series of document-download links on a page  (I have set the browser to automatically download these file types instead of opening them). Upon clicking, one of the following two events may unfold:

1. A pop-up window appears. A button on the pop-up window needs to be clicked to close it before the document is downloaded.
2. A blank pop-up appears momentarily before it disappears on its own when the document download begins.

Here's an excerpt of the script that is written to handle the events above:

```
file_link = tr.find_element_by_xpath('td[5]/a')
file_link.click()
time.sleep(7)  # Allows the blank pop-up to disappear automatically under Event2

agree_button = None

# Checks for the pop-up window
try:
    print "Step 1"
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    print "Step 2"  # SCRIPT STOPS RUNNING HERE
    agree_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="Agree and proceed"]')
    print "Popup found"
except:
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])

# Clicks the button if the pop-up window is found    
if agree_button is not None:
    agree_button.click()
    print "Button clicked"
```

The trouble surfaces when there's high latency in the network for Event 2. Under normal circumstances, the blank pop-up disappears almost instantaneously and the download begins immediately after. However, if the network is slow, the blank pop-up may persist beyond the allocated 7 seconds and that resulted in the script running into "Step 2" before the pop-up window disappears.

Strangely, at this point the script doesn't continue on to look for the `agree_button`. If it does, then that would have triggered the exception and I would be able to revert back to the original window to resume the steps. The script just stalls and does nothing it seems.

Thanks in advance for your time guys!

Comment: is the agree_button on the pop up?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep on waiting until the pop-up disappears. One way you might do this is making below changes in your code:

```
file_link = tr.find_element_by_xpath('td[5]/a')
file_link.click()
time.sleep(7)  # Allows the blank pop-up to disappear automatically under Event2

agree_button = None

# Checks for the pop-up window
try:
    print "Step 1"
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    print "Step 2"  # SCRIPT STOPS RUNNING HERE
    while True:
        agree_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="Agree and proceed"]')
        if agree_button is not None:
            break
        else:
            sleep(7)
    print "Popup found"
except:
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])

# Clicks the button if the pop-up window is found    
if agree_button is not None:
    agree_button.click()
    print "Button clicked"
```

Comment: As explained in my original post, there are 2 types of pop-up events - one comes with the agree_button and the other without. My problem is caused by a delay in the pop-up window that carries no agree_button. Your suggestion would result in an infinite loop, if it doesn't trigger the Selenium exception first due to missing element.